# Switch Case Statement Issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, switch-statement, case, game-center

I am using a switch case statement to determine what data I am receiving in game center multiplayer.

I can't see whats wrong with it but when adding the second case statement it stops working.

I have declared this:

```
typedef enum
{
    kPacketTypeScore,
    kPacketTypeReady,
} EPacketTypes;

typedef struct
{
    EPacketTypes type;
    size_t size;
} SPacketInfo;

typedef struct
{
    SPacketInfo packetInfo;

    int score;
} SScorePacket;

typedef struct
{
    SPacketInfo packetInfo;

    bool ready;
} SReadyPacket;

- (void)match:(GKMatch *)match didReceiveData:(NSData *)data fromPlayer:(NSString *)playerID
{
    // first, assume it's the general SPacketInfo, that way we can access type and size
    packet = (SPacketInfo*)[data bytes];

    scoreData *scoreDat = [scoreData sharedData];
    BOOL rdyReceived;

    switch (packet->type)
    {
        case kPacketTypeScore:
        {
            SScorePacket* scorePacket = (SScorePacket*)packet;

            [scoreLabel setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You: %d Challenger: %d", scoreDat.score, scorePacket->score]];

            break;
        }

        case kPacketTypeReady:
        {
            SReadyPacket* readyPacket = (SReadyPacket*)packet;

            rdyReceived = readyPacket->ready;

            if (rdyReceived == FALSE && scoreDat.mpRdy == TRUE) {
                [rdyLabel setString:@"Waiting for challenger..."];
            }

            if (rdyReceived == TRUE && scoreDat.mpRdy == FALSE) {
                [rdyLabel setString:@"Challenger is waiting... Ready?"];
            }

            if (rdyReceived == TRUE && scoreDat.mpRdy == TRUE) {
                [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:1.0 scene:[mpView node] withColor:ccWHITE]];
            }
            break;
        }

        default:
            CCLOG(@"received unknown packet type %i (size: %u)", packet->type, packet->size);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Causes the application to crash with EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: You are accessing an object that has been released or is no longer in memory. Please use instruments with NSZombie enabled to find what object it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that `data` is a `SReadyPacket*`?
It may be `nil` or some other type.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clarify what exactly the data coming in is. You initially treat it as a `SPacketInfo`, to get the type. Then cast it to one of two other structs, which *contain* an `SPacketInfo`, but are definitely not `SPacketInfo`'s themselves. Then when you try to access members of said struct, you're accessing completely undefined locations.

Either `packet` is actually a packet struct, in which case you should change your switch to:

```
switch (packet->packetInfo->type)
```

Or, it is a `SPacketInfo`, in which case you'll need to get the actual "packet" in some other way.